# Is it possible to call script to verify gsettings element?

Tags: gsettings

I want to add a script to verify gsettings value. If user set a gsetting key:value using gsettings set command, then the script will be called and check whether the set operation was sucessful. Is it possible?

```
<key name="key-with-choices" type="s">
  <choices>
    <choice value='Elisabeth'/>
    <script path="/usr/bin/verify.sh"/>
  </choices>
```